# How to set different properties behind instantiated objects?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am making a game in Unity C# where there are 10 spheres instantiated at the start of the game. When user clicks on any of the sphere, the sphere hides using set active false property. Now what I want is to place bombs behind some of spheres, so that when the user clicks on a sphere which has bomb behind it, the game is over.

**Spheres**

```
List<GameObject> hat;
float q, w, r;
public Spheres()
{
    hat = new List<GameObject>();
    q = -2.5f;w = -2.5f;r = -2.5f;
}

public void AddSphere(GameObject gola)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        GameObject abc = GameObject.Instantiate (gola);
        abc.transform.position = new Vector3 (abc.transform.position.x + q, abc.transform.position.y, abc.transform.position.z + 1.5f);
        hat.Add (abc); q += 1.15f;
    } 
}   

public void HideSphere()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);     
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.transform.gameObject.CompareTag ("Sphere"))
            {
                hit.transform.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Instantiating spheres**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    GameObject abc = GameObject.Instantiate (gola);
    abc.transform.position = new Vector3 (abc.transform.position.x + q, abc.transform.position.y, abc.transform.position.z + 1.5f);
    hat.Add (abc); q += 1.15f;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem with your code.

Comment: Your question is just how to do bunch of stuff. You have to be specific. You can start learning Unity by following one of their project [tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials).

Comment: What the others said plus: Read [ask] on how to improve your question (and to avoid downvotes/closevotes).

Comment: Start with one sphere and on click hide it, On hiding even explode a bomb means show either a image or animation.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
  {
   GameObject abc = GameObject.Instantiate (gola);
   abc.transform.position = new Vector3 (abc.transform.position.x + q, abc.transform.position.y, abc.transform.position.z + 1.5f);
   hat.Add (abc);
   q += 1.15f;
  }

Comment: This is how i am Instantiating spheres, still nothing?

Comment: Add here the code you have to hide the spheres, so we can add some suggestions about how to implement what you are asking for

Comment: List<GameObject> hat;
    float q, w, r;
    public Spheres()
    {
        hat = new List<GameObject>();q = -2.5f;w = -2.5f;r = -2.5f;
    }

    public void AddSphere(GameObject gola)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
            GameObject abc = GameObject.Instantiate (gola);
            abc.transform.position = new Vector3 (abc.transform.position.x + q, abc.transform.position.y, abc.transform.position.z + 1.5f);
            hat.Add (abc);
            q += 1.15f;
        } 

}

Comment: public void HideSphere()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) 
            {
                if (hit.transform.gameObject.CompareTag ("Sphere")) 
                {
                    hit.transform.gameObject.SetActive (false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre,,, Here is the code...!!!

Comment: I really meant to the question. In case you dont know how to format the code,  I (or some other user) will edit the post for you.

Comment: Please tell me how to format the code!?

Comment: Ok I added in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't add any code yet, I will just explain you how I would approach your issue. I assume you have created a GameObject for the spheres which has got attached a script which deactivate the GameObeject or make it not visible onClick(). So the steps to follow now would be:

1. Add a boolean variable to that GameObject called `boolean hasBomb`
2. When you instantiate in your scene the 10 spheres, set randomly that
   boolean as true or false
3. Optional- If you want to add also a bomb prefabs, you can
   instantiate them in the same position of the spheres which hasBomb
   attribute is set to true
4. In the `onClick()` method of the spheres you check if(hasBomb) is set to
   true
5. In case it is true, you Load a new Scene Called GameOver with a text or a menu. Using `Application.LoadLevel("GameOver"`)

Edit with the code you provided in your comments:

```
List<GameObject> hat; 
float q, w, r; 

public Spheres() {     
    hat = new List<GameObject>();
    q = -2.5f;
    w = -2.5f;
    r = -2.5f; 
} 

public void AddSphere(GameObject gola) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        GameObject abc = GameObject.Instantiate (gola); 
        abc.transform.position = new Vector3 (abc.transform.position.x + q, abc.transform.position.y, abc.transform.position.z + 1.5f); 
        hat.Add (abc); 
        q += 1.15f; 
    }     
}

public void HideSphere() {     
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {     
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition); 
        RaycastHit hit; 

        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) { 
            if (hit.transform.gameObject.CompareTag ("Sphere")) {     
                hit.transform.gameObject.SetActive (false);     
            }     
        }     
    }     
}
```

I assume gola is a gameObject you have created in the editor. So instead of tagging that gameObject as "sphere" to later detect if you press on it with the button using the Physics.Raycast, what you can do is to create a script called hideSphere.cs. In that script you should add:

```
public boolean hasBomb;
```

and also

```
function OnMouseDown()
{
  if(hasBomb)
     Application.LoadLevel("GameOver")

  renderer.enabled = false;
  //Or
  //Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Then you should:

1. Add a collider to the gola GameObject (So it detects clicks)
2. Attach the script hideSphere.cs to the gola GameObject

Edit 2:

Now to randomly decide if the sphere has a bomb or not:

```
GameObject abc = GameObject.Instantiate (gola); 
abc.transform.position = new Vector3 (abc.transform.position.x + q, abc.transform.position.y, abc.transform.position.z + 1.5f); 

//Here we decide if it has a Bomb or not
float chance = Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f);
if(chance > 0.75f)
 abc.GetComponent.<hideSphere>().hasBomb = true;

hat.Add (abc);
```

Note: With the line `abc.GetComponent.<hideSphere>().hasBomb = true;` you access to the variable hasBomb, which is a public variable in the script hideSphere.cs, which is attached to the GameObject gola. But in this case you only modify that attribute for the particular instance generated in the current iteration.

Comment: I have attached script with the Main Camera
and I have used a sphere prefab as original object to instantiate.
So, you mean to say that I should add a boolean with prefab of sphere.
But how could I randomly set that bool true or false?
From Inspector?
Or using script?
But if using script, then how to do that?!

Comment: Ok I will try to add that part as well to my answer

Comment: Sorry I am in the office and I can just reply on my free time

Comment: Do you understand how it works?

Comment: Yes, Now Boolean is working, Thanks

Comment: If my answer helped you I appreciate if you accept it. And if you have further questions, feel free to keep asking. I enjoy this kind of challenges

Comment: Yes, Now whole of my game is working according to my idea.!
Thank u very much...!!!
Last question is that how it gets that OnMouseDown, hasBomb is true without raycast?!

Comment: Because OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the GUIElement or Collider. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Answer (score 0):

You place your bomb how sphere children.
When the user click on sphere, you check if your object have a children called "bomb" for example.

```
void OnClick()
{
    if (transform.Find("bomb" != null))
    {
        //gameover 
    }
    else
    {
    gameobject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```